# How to apply tab-link ripple with Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

With `md-ink-ripple` we can apply ripple to other angular elements such as `grid` or `title`. I wonder if there is a similar attribute we can call for the ripple effect on the tab.

Example: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

If not, I like to know how the ripple effect shown was done.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems outdated because Angular Material tabs already have a ripple effect on them when clicked, and it is achieved by dynamic application of `md-ink-ripple`.

See the demo:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Comment: Yeah the old tab ripple effect was gone so you probably didn't know what I was talking about. It's a very cool special effect.